# Why does backgrounding `script` from a makefile drastically increase cpu usage?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, bsd

First a little bit of context: I'm calling this is inside a shell script that's called from make that's executed concurrently with `make -j4`.  I have not found any reliable way to atomically write to stdout so I backgrounded the process and found it to work fairly well.  Unfortunately, it seems that doing so consumes about double the CPU.  Note that outside of the makefile, the commands both work in effectively the same way.

A :

```
script -q /dev/null big_long_command 2>&1 > /dev/null &
PID=$!
wait $PID
RET=$?
```

B :

```
script -q /dev/null big_long_command 2>&1 > /dev/null
PID=$!
wait $PID
RET=$?
```

I should also mention that `big_long_command` doesn't output anything under normal circumstances though it is a cpu intensive process that will max out a single core (C++ compilation).  Output from top shows that with method A, `big_long_command` and `script` have roughly equal cpu utilization (maxed out), whereas with B, `script` consumes nothing at all.  Why is this?

*Note, `script` is the name of the command, not the shell script.

Comment: in B, your job will be running foreground, which means the shell is suspended while that job is running. suspended shell = no cpu. in the background case, the shell WILL be running, and `wait` will poll $PID continually until that job exits.

Comment: I think I should reword, or perhaps it's the same thing, because the processes with high cpu usage are `big_long_command` and `script`, not the shell script.

Comment: I don't think `wait` polls; it simply blocks until the shell receives a `SIGCHLD` event.

Comment: @chepner That's exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Why are you using `script`?  What is that first `/dev/null` doing on the command lines?   Also, I hope you do realize that putting a command in the background within a Makefile effectively hides it from make

Comment: @GregA.Woods It's been a while, but looking at the above code, the purpose seems to be to discard all output and block until the process exits. I certainly understand that Make won't be able to read the output of the process, but give that both stderr and stdout are sent to `/dev/null`, it seems that I don't care what the console output is at all. I forget what the context of this problem is, but according to the question, running the command from Make has the effect of drastically increasing the CPU usage.

Comment: Well, if you don't know why you wrapped the command in a call to `script` and put that into a makefile rule, then perhaps that's the problem.  `script` has no use whatsoever in a makefile.  Perhaps it spins out of control when it is run with its standard input attached to `/dev/null`.  Putting a program in the background and then using `wait` right away is pointless in any situation, and it might not work at all in an makefile (unless it is on the same line as the `&`).

Comment: So, I want to be clear: I'm not asking anyone about the utility of the above statement. I'm just asking for an explanation of the observed behavior.